# Not able to install `Hyper-V` within my virtual machine (Windows 8.1 Basic)

Tags: windows-phone-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am running a windows 8 (64bit basic) machine , since hyper v is not available for win 8 , i tired to install win 8.1 basic (64bit) in virtual box to start windows phone 8 development.

As first step i enabled Intel Virtualization in the BIOS screen  and tried to look for hyper v feature in VM's features , but could not able to find it.

So tried to run intel tool in the Host(win 8) and VM(win 8.1)

1. The result for the host machine :

[image: result1]

2. The result for the VM :

[image: result2]

Additionally , i also tried to run coreinfo.exe -v tool on command promt

1. The result for the host machine :

[image: result1]

2. The result for the VM :

[image]

I would be thankful , if anyone help me to enable hyper v on my VM

Please also clarify , is it possible enable hyper-v (on my host machine) if i upgrade my main host machine from win 8 basic to win 8.1 basic  ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Hyper-V is a Windows 8.1 Pro feature. It is not available on Windows 8.1 Basic. You will need Windows 8.1 Pro to run Hyper-V

See [Compare Windows 8.1 Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx)

You do not need Hyper-V to develop Windows Phone apps. You can use Windows 8.1 Basic and Visual Studio 2013. Without Hyper-V you cannot run the emulator, but you can test on a physical device.

You cannot use Windows 8.0 Basic to develop Windows Phone apps. You'll need Windows 8.0 Pro (to develop Windows Phone 8 apps only, with Visual Studio 2012) or an Windows 8.1 (to develop Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 apps with Visual Studio 2013).

See [Getting started with developing for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402529(v=vs.105).aspx) for Windows 8 requirements and [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) for Windows 8.1 requirements.